# Math.random function + using ngSwitch JS Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use a Math.random function to generate a number between 20 and 100 in conjunction with the ngSwitch directive so I can display a letter grade based on a grading scale. But I am not sure how I should exactly format the coding for this at least on the HTML page (the ngSwitch portion).

So far, in my component.ts file I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: '.app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements onInit {
  title = 'title';
  x: number;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  }
}
```

Here is the app.component.html file:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
<div style="text-align:center">
   <h1>
      Welcome to {{x}}.
   </h1>
</div>

<div [ngswitch]="switch_expression">
    <p *ngSwitchCase="1">A</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="2">B</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="3">C</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="4">D</p>
    <p *ngSwitchDefault>F</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

For whatever reason, no matter what I put on my HTML code, the page keeps showing as blank whenever I compile the code. Any ideas? Am I headed on the right track?

Comment: Could you please show your template as well ?

Comment: Hey @avcajaraville, do you mean the HTML page?

Comment: The app.component.html file

Comment: @avcajaraville Okay, just added above. Thanks for replying, any insights would help. I am not sure where to start and my HTML page keeps blanking when I compile it, so I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with: `[ngswitch]="switch_expression"` ?

Comment: What you posted as the template is an interesting mix between the index.html and the component-template, which will never ever work. I suggest you take a look at an angular hello world app to understand its concepts.

Comment: I also notice that you use switch_expression but that is not defined in your component.  If a variable is not defined sometimes it will show a blank page and the console will dump an error (as well as the terminal running ng serve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @acincognito mentioned, this code will never ever work properly!

There is a lot of conceptual errors here.

First, you are trying to access component properties outside of the actual component. Look how your use of `{{x}}` it's outside the actual `app-root` component, so this `{{x}}` you are referencing it's outside of the component scope.

The interface you need to implement is `OnInit` not `onInit` (capital letter matters!).

Then there is also this `[ngswitch]="switch_expression"` which doesn't make any sense since you never defined your `[ngswitch]="switch_expression"`. Furthermore, `ngSwitch` directive was not written properly, it should be `[ngSwitch]`.

Your templateUrl declaration is not a valid resource, you need to change it into `templateUrl: './app.component.html'`

As others suggest, have a look at [angular docs](https://angular.io/start), they also have a stack blitz example you play with.

I hope it helps to put you back on track!

I have created a small stack blitz with a solution that might work for you. [Check it out here!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e99bc4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: So the HTML file is just what I have so far, I am not sure how to tie the ngSwitch directive with the Math.random function. Is there any documentation anywhere that shows how to do that?

Comment: Have a closer look at the posted example and review it carefully. It is not the same. You need to differentiate between the index.html and the layout file. Also, be careful with capital letters! Regarding documentation, angular official docs are huge and very well explained, so, yeah, there is quite a lot of docs. on the subject.